# How can I calculate the week starting days between two days?

Tags: php, symfony1

For ex-

```
        Day1    2011-03-28
        Day2    2011-04-25
```

week starting days

```
                 2011-03-28
                 2011-4-4
                 2011-4-11
                 2011-4-18
                 2011-04-25
```

Comment: Please point out why none of the 5000+ duplicates for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=week+starting+days+php didnt answer your question.

Comment: Because he's too lazy to search?

Comment: Since I can't decide which duplicate best fits this (many of them do), I'm closing this as too localized.

Answer (score 1):

```
function print_monday_dates($startdate, $enddate)
{
  if (date('N', $startdate) != 1)
    $startdate = strtotime("next monday", $startdate);

  while ($startdate <= $enddate)
  {
    echo date("Y-m-d", $startdate)."\n";
    $startdate = strtotime("next monday", $startdate);
  }
}

echo print_monday_dates(strtotime("2011-03-28"), strtotime("2011-04-25"));
```

Comment: Doesn't work if $startdate is not monday, it will print this day out too. For example `$startdate = strtotime("2011-03-27")`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Edited answer, should be fixed. EDIT: aww, now it doesn't works if date is monday. I'll borrow your `if (date('N', $tstart) == 1)` :)

Comment: Error again... with first line in function you jumped over first monday in output if $stardate is really monday. For example use condition `date('N')==1` to check if $startday is monday then on **true** print it out, otherwise skip first date. However, test your code and you will see that there are no 2011-03-28 in the list.

Comment: I've noticed that, thanks. Should be finally ok now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function

```
  function getAllMondays($startdate, $enddate) {
    $res = array();
    $tstart = strtotime($startdate);
    $tend = strtotime($enddate);
    if (date('N', $tstart) == 1) $res[] = date('Y-m-d', $tstart);
    while ($tstart <= $tend) {
      $tstart = strtotime('next monday', $tstart);
      $res[] = date('Y-m-d', $tstart);
      }
    return $res;
    }
```

and use it this way

```
  $allmondays = getAllMondays('2011-03-28', '2011-04-25');
  print_r($allmondays);
```

to get something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011-03-28
    [1] => 2011-04-04
    [2] => 2011-04-11
    [3] => 2011-04-18
    [4] => 2011-04-25
)
```

Injoy

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP, but logically can you not get the first Monday between those dates then recursively add 7 days to get each Monday until it exceeds the final date supplied?

Comment: There's no point in involving recursion to achieve this.

Comment: sorry - should have said loop :-)